# Laravel: dynamic property loading when not required in loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have customer model and product model joined by subscriptions table. When i run something like
`$customers = Customer::with(['products' => function($query) { $query->where('somecondition');}])->get();`

And if i loop over customers like :

```
    foreach ($customers as $customer){
      foreach($customer->products as $product) {
        # do something
      }
    }
```

It loads the entire products of the customer ignoring the condition above by using dynamic property.. How to fix this?

My classes are

```
class Customer extends Model{

    public function products(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'subscriptions')->withTimestamps()
    ->withPivot('qty', 'start_date', 'end_date');

    }
}
```

I am calling this in another function :

```
           $customers = $request->user()->customers()->where('id', $request['customer_id'])->whereHas(
            'customerstatuses', function ($q) use ($p){
                $q->where('start_date', '<' ,$p)
                    ->where('end_date', '>' ,$p)
                    ->where('active_yn', '=' ,'1');
        })->with(['products'=>  function ($query) use ($p){
                $query->whereHas('productstatuses' ,function ($q) use ($p){
                $q->where('start_date', '<' ,$p)
                ->where('end_date', '>' ,$p)
                ->where('active_yn', '=' ,'1');
                })->wherePivot('start_date', '<', $p )
                    ->wherePivot('end_date', '>', $p)])->get();
```

Comment: Can you show the real code please?

Answer (score 0):

you are doing this wrong.. you should do it like this

```
$customers = Customer::with(['products' => function($query) { $query->where('somecondition');}]);
```

the relation condition will be in `array`.

Comment: That was a typo. But the real question is that it calls the dynamic property in looping when i dont want it

Comment: oh okay. That's strange. Did you try `dd()` on `$customers` and then see what is it returning? Please post your code

Comment: But its logical right? $customer is an instance of Customer  so it loads products by using the dynamic property

Comment: @qurius, please show real code with real `somecondition` part.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin added above